# "Class not registered" when using Microsoft.Web.Administration on Windows 7 after installing updates

Tags: .net, iis-7, com, azure, 64-bit

A Windows 7 (64-bit) system runs the following code under Windows Azure Compute Emulator (SDK version 1.5)

```
Site site = new ServerManager();
```

which yields the following exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {B15183DD-75F9-42DF-8E57-C8B57692F134} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

The class id mentioned in the message refers to a 32-bit .dll in Program Files (x86). Since the Azure role code is 64-bit this won't fly.

This behavior was not observed until some Windows updates were rolled in when installing Windows Phone SDK 7.1

How can this problem be best resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was traced to having IIS Express installed on the same machine - uninstalling it restored normal operation.